# Showing an integral is divergent

Tags: integration

I'm not really sure where to start with showing:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac 1{\beta t}e^{-t/\beta} dt = \infty?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral diverges as $t\to 0$ you can show that $e^{-t/\beta} \ge 1 - \frac t \beta $ then take 
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-t/\beta}}{\beta t}dt \ge \int_{0}^1 \frac{e^{-t/\beta}}{\beta t}dt \ge\int_{0}^1 \frac{1 - t/\beta}{\beta t}dt $$

Comment: Would I show $e^{-t/\beta} \ge 1 - \frac t \beta $ by drawing a graph? Is there a more rigorous way of doing it?